# How to use group-only permission in the application?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

How to use group-only permission in the application?

I have a user who is in a group1.

I intend to get the permission to get the permission.

How to do this?

```
class home(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.has_perm('group1'):
           return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Try to use `request.user.has_perm('app_name.group1')`

Comment: Thank you. There is something wrong. I did so request.user.has_perm ('app_name.group1') and request.user.has_perm ('app_name.jfahdjf'). To try. Both returns True.

Comment: Note that if the user is a superuser, `has_perm` will *always* return `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a member of a group isn't the same as having a permission. To check that a user s in a group `group1`, you would do:

```
if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='group1').exists():
```

You might find the [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) useful.

```
# It's recommended to use CamelCase for class based view names, 
# i.e. Home instead of home
class Home(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'

    def test_func(self):
        # Use self.request.user.is_authenticated() in Django <= 1.9
        return self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.groups.filter(name='group1').exists()

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'index.html')
```